# Server side validation if Javascript disabled on user's browser

Tags: asp.net, server-side-validation

I have developed a small form with 3 input type = text and one input type = submit button. The end user fills the form and submit it, but no data inserted into backend table. (probably empty form is submitted). I get to know that Javascript is disabled on user's browser. Now i want to do server side validation. How i validate my form on server side? I need a piece of code to validate form on server side (code behinde) ? I need code in asp.net

Comment: Are you using built-in framework validation controls or custom validation using javascript for client side validation?

Comment: I want to validate my form at server side, but i dont know how i validate ? I dont want to use server side .net validation Controls

Comment: Then you just have to check each of your control for valid values before doing any action. Just check the controls.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not ask for straight forward code on this forum. But either way here is a great resource for asp.net form validation: [MSDN - Validating ASP.NET Server Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx)

Essentially, assuming you are using C#, you might do something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<script runat="server">

   void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
   Label1.Text = "Page is valid!";
   }

</script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
       <form runat="server">
        <p>
            <asp:TextBox id="TextBox1" 
            runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            &nbsp; 
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
            id="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="Required!" 
            ControlToValidate="TextBox1">
            </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button id="Button1" onclick="Button1_Click" 
             runat="server" Text="Button"></asp:Button>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label id="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My recommendation is to try and Google some and look for tutorials - there are [pretty informative ones out there](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/a0z2h4sw(v=vs.100).aspx) available with easy step by step directions.

Happy coding!